# How To Test A Web Hook File In A Browser

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, webhooks

I have never used a webhook and currently tying to get use one, below is my code in php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Handle incoming messages from WhatsApp senders.
 */

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$webhook = json_decode($body, true);

print_r($webhook['results']);

?>
```

I have a service that POSTS the data i need, when i run the script in the browser and then POSTS data, nothing happens. Im i doing something wrong or the problem could be from the POST service.

Comment: Did you provide any url  to the service that posts data ?

Comment: Yes, http://myurl.com/mywebhook.php

Answer (score 0):

You should Try using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) , It allows us to post the required data to url , You are not doing it wrong its right but testing of data can only be done runtime once your url is loaded the browser it wont capture any data you will have to add condition in your script like

```
<?php

/**
 * Handle incoming messages from WhatsApp senders.
 */

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if($_POST){

$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$webhook = json_decode($body, true);
print_r($webhook['results']);
}


?>
```

And then using postman post data to this file then you can check the posted data